# Jenkins Groovy and Active Choices Reactive Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a perl script that return list of names taken from DB:

perl -w /tmp/testdb.pl

```
"Dana Ron Emily Ethan James Brandon Josef"
```

I want that Jenkins will show them in the **Active Choices Reactive Parameter** depends by the value chosen in the previous parameter

This is the groovy script I have:

```
    def command = "perl -w /tmp/testdb.pl"
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()              

    def output = proc.in.text
    List modifiedList = output.split(' ')
    return modifiedList
```

When trying to run the build, it shows an empty list
When I run this groovy script from command line (on the same jenkins machine) it works:

```
[Dana, Ron, Emily, Ethan, James, Brandon, Josef]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In parameter configuration set `return ["error"]` in **Fallback Script** and try again to check if you get an error. Also try you script in `{jenkins_url}/script`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
List modifiedList = output.tokenize(' ')
```

Instead of:

```
List modifiedList = output.split(' ')
```